# List of all companies on AngelList via API

Tags: api

https://angel.co/api/spec/startups

What would the best approach for hitting every company that is listed on AngelList? My first guess would be to query all the numbers up until 250k, the number of companies on angelList, using this endpoint `https://api.angel.co/1/startups/45435`

There surely has to be a better way of doing this though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is possible via their API. And the API endpoint that you have mentioned in your question is the correct one. I have written a PHP component to achieve this. You can use this exporter application to download the start-ups data for each country into a CSV file : [AngelList Data Exporter](http://sandbox.tsk-webdevelopment.com/angel-list-exporter/)

I hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Angel.co does not expose its api anymore. So you have to parse the website to get any data.
Also a quick google search would give you a few websites which have different datasets from angel.co website.